# Cycles textures render black

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing

I have a problem with my interior design render. I use some textures on tiles (cuboids). And on one camera view they render textured, but on the other - at copied objects with the same material, but in different location and rotation- they render black. The normals of the objects are fine. I copied my scene to another file, and as I rotated everything in the scene 90 degrees, the objects that rendered black were now perfectly fine, while the ones that previosly were textured, rendered black... I use cycles as my engine. Does anyone have a clue what is going on?

[image: Material nodes]

Comment: Possibly a problem with your normal map?